# Updating the database and leaving 5 so that it is not affected

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to update the database but I want to leave 5 posts so they are not affected and the rest are updated as requested.

I tried the method below but it did not work, is someone able to crack this code.
Thank you.

```
UPDATE `post` SET active = '1' 
WHERE `user` = '".$my['id']."' 
NOT IN (SELECT id FROM `post` 
WHERE `user` = '".$my['id']."' LIMIT 5)
```

Comment: mysql doesn't support LIMIT in subquery, instead you can use JOIN.

Comment: "but it did not work" -- What does that mean in detail?

Comment: The code above does not change anything

Comment: [Edit] the question and post a [example].

Comment: Besides that limit is not allowed in in clauses, what do you want to accomplish exactly in you where clause

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE post SET active = '1' 
WHERE `user` = '".$my['id']."' and id not IN (
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT id FROM post
        WHERE `user` = '".$my['id']."'
        ORDER BY id ASC  
        LIMIT 0, 5
    ) tmp
)
```

Comment: Wow this works, I have 3 days trying to solve this problem. thank you master

Answer (score 0):

Move the subquery to a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE post p LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT p.id
        FROM post p
        WHERE p.user = '".$my['id']."'
        LIMIT 5
       ) pp
       ON p.id = pp.id
    SET active = '1' 
WHERE p.user = '".$my['id']."' AND
      pp.id IS NULL;
```

MySQL does not easily allow you to refer to the table being updated in a subquery in the `WHERE` or `SET` clauses.  However, it allows `JOIN`s, which are the recommended way to solve this problem.